# String.IsNullOrEmpty()

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

Recently I've noticed that when we've been doing string comparisons in our .NET code we have been safeguarding against null references. This check seems unnecessary in VB.NET because it overloads the equality operator and performs this null ref check for us. Do you all agree ?

See examples below:

```
        Dim myStringVariable As String

        ' Unnecessary in VB.NET
        If myStringVariable Is Nothing OrElse myStringVariable = "" Then
        End If

        ' Unnecessary in VB.NET
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringVariable) Then
        End If

        ' This will work
        If myStringVariable = "" Then
        End If

        ' Also acceptable if you don't like using hard coded constants
        If myStringVariable = String.Empty Then
        End If
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifically for equality tests you may be right.  However, equality tests are not the only thing you do with strings.

I have not done much VB.Net, but I strongly suspect that

```
myStringVariable.Length
```

will blow up if myStringVariable is null, er... Nothing.

Answer (score 3):

It's never unnecessary to be explicit about what you're doing.  If someone who is working on your code reads `String.IsNullOrEmpty` they know that you meant treat null and empty the same way.

If someone who is working on your code reads `myStringVariable = String.Empty`, they have to wonder if you meant to handle nulls and empties the same way or if you made an oversight.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, combining all of those checks is hella redundant.

Why not simplify it to simply:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(myStringVariable) Then
    ' do whatever
End If
```